# How can I load an object graph in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have some relational data that I need to fetch

```
from user in Users
  .Include("UserCategoryPermissions")
  .Include("UserResourcePermissions")
  .Include("UserPermissions.Permission.Application")
  .Include("UserGroupMembers.UserGroup.UserGroupPermissions.Permission.Application")
where user.Id == 3
```

Entity Framework Core is fetching this data by executing multiple queries. All I want to do is load an object graph into memory (no projection), and multiple-queries are going to really slow things down.

I can pre-load these objects by doing a massive query with lots of joins

```
from a in A
join b in B on a.Id equals b.A_Id into bJoin from b in bJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
join c in C on b.Id equals c.B_Id into cJoin from c in cJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
join x in X on a.Id equals x.A_Id into xJoin from x in xJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
// etc
select new {
  a, b, c, x
}
```

But having to do this every time I want to fetch data would be a real pain. Is there a way I can get Entity Framework Core to pre-load a graph of data? Ideally, I want it to work from an array of strings, where each string identifies a path (as I have above), but I'll be happy to learn of any way these graphs could be passed via a parameter to a method.

Comment: That's just how EF has implemented it now. But don't conclude too easily that one call will perform better. Includes in EF6 (always one call) tend to slow down queries considerably.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm seeing a difference of 250-300ms for 6 queries vs 60ms for a single query with joins.

Comment: That's quite convincing :) I know they're working on it, but I can't find the issue number right now.

Comment: Multiple queries are "by design" - see for instance [#9987: Simple query with Include() executes 2 SQL queries instead of 1](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9987). The only optimizations are for 0..1 cardinality (reference) navigation properties or specific cases like [#10001: Query: Improve SQL for queries which are projecting out single result from collection in projection](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10001)

Answer (score 1):

I'd normally use the lambda syntax and it fetches all data in one call:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
...

var userFound = context.Users
    .Include(user => user.UserCategoryPermissions)
    .Include(user => user.UserResourcePermissions)
    .Include(user => user.UserPermissions)
    .ThenInclude(map => map.Permission)
    .ThenInclude(permission => permission.Application)
    .Include(user => user.UserGroupMembers)
    .ThenInclude(members => members.UserGroup)
    .ThenInclude(group => group.UserGroupPermissions)
    .ThenInclude(map => map.Permissions)
    .ThenInclude(permission => permission.Application)
    .Where(user => user.Id == 3);
```

Be aware that within the lambda of the `Include` and `ThenInclude` intellisense not works properly. Simply blind type the correct property name and it works.

Comment: This doesn't make any difference, it's nothing but a different syntax achieving the same effect. EF-core just runs multiple queries for Includes.

Comment: No, this generates an additional query for every include